# Laravel AWS S3 Adapter class not found

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to upload files to Amazon s3 using Laravel 5.8, it actually works on locally but I am unable to get it to work online. I got error:

```
Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found
```

I've run 'composer dump-autoload', 'composer install'commands I've even tried to upload vendor folder. The .env file is the same locally and online so I'm pretty sure that is not a credentials problem.

This is my post code:

```php
public function postUpload(StoreImage $request)
    {
        $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put('images/registry', $request->file, 'public');
        $request->merge([
            'size' => $request->file->getClientSize(),
            'path' => $path,
            'auth_by' => $request->patient
        ]);
        $this->image->create($request->only('path', 'title', 'size', 'auth_by'));
        return back()->with('success', 'Image Successfully Saved');
    }
```

So I'm getting this error: 
[image: Error]

Please any help would be great :).

Comment: what version of laravel?

Comment: i'm using 5.8.*

Comment: Please share more details, and the error message in readable text form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install AWS adapter package

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What was the output of composer command?
Did you run it in your laravel project directory?